# Why docker-compose build can't run command but docker build can?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10 AS builder
RUN npm install multi-file-swagger -g
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY swagger/* ./
ARG API_HOST
ENV APP_HOST=$API_HOST
RUN sed -i 's+replace_host+'"$API_HOST"'+g' index.yaml
RUN multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json

FROM golang:1.12
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
VOLUME /go/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/ swagger/
CMD ["app"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - API_HOST=api.my-real-domain.com
    volumes:
      - ./:/go/src/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

If run `docker build` only:

```
docker build -t myapp . --build-arg API_HOST=api.my-real-domain.com
```

It can run the commands:

```
RUN sed -i 's+replace_host+'"$API_HOST"'+g' index.yaml
RUN multi-file-swagger index.yaml > index.json
```

And when lunch the container, I can find the `index.json` exists.

But if use `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, then check the `index.json` in container, can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you overwrite all your files in `app` folder by using:

```
volumes:
  - ./:/go/src/app
```

you need to remove the `volume` section from your `compose`

Comment: The `VOLUME` in your Dockerfile isn't doing anything either and I'd strongly suggest removing it.  (Its two most obvious effects will be preventing later `RUN` commands from working and leaking anonymous volumes when you `docker run` the container; it has no bearing on whether it's possible to hide the image contents like this or not.)